# Entity Framework - Group By Sum

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

This is a relatively new area for me. I have two entities: `Inquiries` and `Categories`.

Each `Inquiry` has a category and a property indicating an integer value (called `TotalTimeSpent`), and each category has multiple inquiries.

What I want to do is generate a view that is grouped by categories while summing all the inquiries in that one category.

My code at the moment is:

```
var catgroup = db.CATEGORies.GroupBy(i => i.CATNAME).Sum(c => c.)
```

Obviously each grouping has multiple inquiries in it, so when I am doing the c=> c. it is not bringing back the property that I need to sum with only the group extensions (like `FirstOrDefault`).

How do I continue from here so I can sum `TotalTimeSpent` for each inquiry based on the above grouping?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this instead:

```sql
var catgroup = db.CATEGORies.GroupBy(c => c.CATNAME)
    .Select(g => new {
        g.Key, 
        SUM = g.Sum(s => s.Inqueries.Select(t => t.TotalTimeSpent).Sum())
    });
```

Comment: Hi Giorgi, thanks for your reply. That didn't work. I don't see the CATNAME or any other properties when I do the c.Key.

Comment: Are you sure there are other columns in db.CATEGORies besides of CATNAME?

Comment: Yes that was my bad. When grouping by one field you select Key directly! Check now.

Comment: Thanks again! I've got to that point but my TotalTimeSpent is in a navigation property called Inquiries, so I need to use k.Inquiries.TotalTimeSpent. At that point TotalTimeSpent seems to be a collection, so how do enumerate through that for the sum?

Comment: That didn't work - I think I know why I was having problems previously. My TotalTimeSpent is a none mapped entity, its getter calculates the totaltimespent from another table and returns that value when it is accessed from its entity.  final error: ""The specified type member 'TotalTimeSpent' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported." I may need to go back to the drawing board for how I am going to do this. Thank you very much for the time you have spent on this, your answer is correct so I will mark it as such!

Comment: there is no Inqueries field